# Installing Mura 6.2 Code Base and Lucee Configuration

Tags: lucee, mura

1. I have created empty database at MySQL and created DSN at Lucee admin.
2. Did not get any Mura setup form as mentioned in the step4 of Installing Mura Code base.
3. ## application.contentServer.handleRootRequest()# was the only output.
4. What are the other config steps to be done at Lucee admin.
5. Understand that nothing to be done at index.cfm of  my Muradev root directory.
   I have  Windows 7, Apache2.4.18, MySQL5.7, Lucee Tomcat8 and  Lucee 4.5.2.018
   Why I did not get Mura setup form? 
   I have selected rule2 in the web.config ( XML) and Lucee throws error. screen shot attached.
   What is the config to be done at Lucee/Tomcat.[Lucee error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOcvC.jpg).

Comment: It seems that server is not correctly configured, are you sure your virtualhost is pointing to correct document path?